# What do these terms mean?

Tags: shader

I am learning to create games with unity and thought that I might as well learn some shader writing.
But, I was soon confused with terms such as alpha, beta, hsv, emissive, specular, etc.
So, I was hoping if there is a site, wiki or book or a tutorial series where these have been explained since I don't have a clear definition of these terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Alpha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) is transparency.
- [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) stands for Hue, Saturation, Value, and is a way of representing colors, similar to RGB (Red, Green, Blue)
- Emissive lighting occurs when objects are "illuminated by themselves," such as a neon sign.
- [Specular reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_reflection) is a mirror-style reflection, such as from the surfact of water or from an actual mirror.

[This article](http://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/ComputerGraphics/LightingAndShading.html) describes many of these topics.

Comment: well, this was all I needed, Thank you!